# Batch insert into Databricks through JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, databricks, dbeaver, batch-insert

I'm trying to import data to Databricks table from csv using dbeaver through JDBC.
DBeaver v21.2.0
Databricks JDBC Driver v2.6.22

I've tried enabling several options including "Use multi-row value insert" and "Use transactions", but it seems that values are still inserted row by row.

Is there any way to perform multi-row insert? As for now it takes too long to import whole csv file (about 50 rows per minute).